# Itunes fails to sync App

Tags: ios, xcode4, itunes

I migrate my app from xcode3 to xcode4.2. Everything goes fine if I use xcode3. But when I try to sync ad-hoc app generated by xcode4, it always show iTunes Sync xxx app failed to sync. The most weird thing is that if I sync the app that created by xcode3 first. Then delete the app on the device. Replace the app and sync again, The error won't display. The app built by xcode4.2 will successfully set on the device. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Wait so you fixed the problem? After deleting the first build from Xcode 3, the Xcode 4 build works?

Comment: i found i made a stupid mistake. I didn't update the provisioning profile in xcode4.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the app through it is better to use provising profile if you want to send the app to the client/User then try with Adhoc Certificate.